# Airflow : Is it possible to configure task-level timeout in a DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow : Is it possible to configure task-level timeout in a DAG .

I wished to prevent  a task from running indefinitely . According to my understanding sla parameters will come in place only once the task gets completed and overshoots the SLA .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For timeouts on Operators in Airflow you can add the `execution_timeout` parameter. From the docs:

> exuction_timeout (datetime.timedelta) –  max time allowed for the execution of this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail

It expects a `datetime.timedelta`, e.g. `timedelta(hours=1)` for a max of 1 hour for the task.

Note that for sensors `execution_timeout` does not work. Sensors expect a `timeout` parameter instead.

Comment: I found that sensors will still in fact work whether you have a timeout or execution_timeout, or even both in place. While it may have been designed to only use execution_timeout for normal tasks, and timeout for sensor tasks, they both seem to use the allotted number of retries and function the same way (killing the current run and either going into a retry, or failing if no retries remain). The only difference I've seen so far are the errors that they throw. "airflow.exceptions.AirflowSensorTimeout: Snap. Time is OUT." versus "airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: Timeout, PID: "